# what is RouterOS used for in my network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I can access my Linksys router's configuration at http://192.168.1.1.

At http://192.168.0.2/ to http://192.168.0.7/, they show the configuration pages for different versions of RouterOS. The username and password are not the same as those I used to access my router's configuration page.

What is RouterOS used for in my network?  Is it installed on my router? Is it the OS or firmware running on my router?

What are the default username and password to access its configuration webpage?

What does its configuration webpage allow me to do?

Thanks.

```
$ traceroute superuser.com
traceroute to superuser.com (190.93.247.58), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  1.289 ms  1.788 ms  2.244 ms
 2  10.235.28.1 (10.235.28.1)  6.717 ms  6.931 ms  7.084 ms
 3  cci-209150226181.clarityconnect.net (209.150.226.181)  12.114 ms  12.481 ms  12.662 ms
 4  cci-209150226245.clarityconnect.net (209.150.226.245)  13.747 ms  13.605 ms  13.940 ms
 5  clarityconnect.fltg.net (98.159.210.49)  15.421 ms  15.630 ms  16.526 ms
 6  xe-8-3-0.bar1.Syracuse2.Level3.net (4.26.24.33)  52.766 ms  32.621 ms  10.453 ms
 7  * * *
 8  telia-level3-10.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.68.110.82)  16.098 ms  20.152 ms  19.890 ms
 9  nyk-bb1-link.telia.net (213.155.131.136)  20.449 ms  20.688 ms  21.085 ms
10  nyk-b2-link.telia.net (213.155.130.28)  21.393 ms  22.181 ms  22.412 ms
11  cloudflare-ic-301663-nyk-b2.c.telia.net (213.248.77.162)  22.662 ms  124.887 ms  16.149 ms
12  190.93.247.58 (190.93.247.58)  16.543 ms  17.175 ms  16.745 ms


$ traceroute 192.168.0.2
traceroute to 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  4.103 ms  7.418 ms  7.526 ms
 2  10.235.28.1 (10.235.28.1)  10.167 ms  10.399 ms  10.614 ms
 3  cci-209150226181.clarityconnect.net (209.150.226.181)  11.126 ms  11.338 ms  12.709 ms
 4  cci-209150226142.clarityconnect.net (209.150.226.142)  15.422 ms  15.613 ms  15.855 ms
 5  10.150.228.9 (10.150.228.9)  17.153 ms  16.759 ms  17.333 ms
 6  10.150.228.1 (10.150.228.1)  25.243 ms  24.085 ms  25.122 ms
 7  192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2)  25.390 ms  25.574 ms  27.308 ms
```

Comment: Please run `tracert superuser.com` and include the output in your question.

Comment: I don't have `tracert` on my Ubuntu. Which package to install?

Comment: On Linux, it’s usually called `traceroute`.

Comment: done. Could you explain the output?

Comment: I’ll update my answer in a few seconds. In the meantime, you could run `traceroute 192.168.0.2` and add the output, too.

Comment: Is 192.168.0.2 in my internal network or in the external network (i.e. the Internet) or some intermediate network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your router’s IP is 192.168.**1**.1 while the devices running RouterOS are indeed accessible via 192.168.**0**.2-7, they’re most definitely not in *your* network.

RouterOS is a MikroTik product and not related to your Linksys router in any way.

**Update**
From the `traceroute` output, we can see that your ISP, which provides wireless internet access, manages its internal network in the `10.0.0.0/8` range and then performs [carrier-grade NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). (This is common practice because the IPv4 address space has been fully exhausted and only small blocks remain for assignment.)

Your internal network is `192.168.1.0/24`, that means all devices with IPs from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.254` could belong to devices local to *your* network.

It’s very likely these MikroTik devices are used by your ISP to run its backbone network and/or wireless base stations.

**Update 2**
From the `traceroute 192.168.0.2` output, we can discern these devices are definitely not local to your network or even anywhere near you. Because the path never leaves your ISP’s network, it’s likely networking equipment maintained by the ISP. It’s, as you call it, an “intermediate network”, although your regular internet traffic doesn’t go through it.

It’s rather questionably why they would route their traffic like that or use common home network subnets, but that’s a different matter. :)

Comment: Thanks! How can I find out the my local internal network's internal ip range?

Comment: @Tim I updated my answer, if you didn’t notice. Do you want to know anything else?

Answer (score 1):

RouterOS is a Linux distro made by [MikroTik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MikroTik) for their proprietary routing hardware.

My guess is that you have one or more MikroTik devices on your network.  These were likely provided by your ISP.  Since they are in a different subnet (192.168.0.0/24 vs 192.168.1.0/24), that usually indicates the router hardware that directly connects to the ISP network, like your cable/DSL modem.

The default username and password for RouterOS is **admin** and a blank password.  However, the default IP for RouterOS is 192.168.88.1, so I believe it has probably been configured by your ISP, so the username/password are likely changed.

The reason you may be seeing multiple IP addresses is that the MikroTik box may have multiple interfaces.  Unless you provide more details, there's not much more we can tell you at this point.

Comment: each ip is for a different version of RouterOS.

Comment: @Tim then it means you have two different MikroTik devices on your network.  And they are definitely on *your* network, though they do not share a subnet with your Linksys router.  The private IP address means they are definitely local.